# Getting model id in different models create form in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i'm working on a project in backbone and are having some problems when trying to create a new model.

I have an application with two different models where one depends on another.

My models are Books and Authors, and to create a book I need the id of the author. 
This is where my problem lies, I have no idea how to get this using backbone?

if I'm not precise enough please ask.

Thank you!

Comment: do you have `author`'s model or collection when you creating `book`'s model?

Comment: I actually found a way of doing this, but don't know if it is a good one. I'm adding the book in the author view, were I have access to the author id.

Comment: it is good if you find a way, it is your app and you know better then us how to build app's architecture. but, it was good if it would like that, `book` doesn't depends on `author`, and `book`'s collection was field of `author` -- the way is easier.
good like:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
// create Book model
var book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        Title: "",
        Desc: "",
        Author: 0
    }
});

// create Author model
var author = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        Name: "",
        ID: 1
    }
});


var markTwain = new author({
    Name: "Mark Twain"
});

var huckleberryFinn = new book({
    Author: markTwain.get("ID")
});

console.log(huckleberryFinn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a subcollection. You will end up having an authors collection holding the Autors models. And then you might attach a books collection to every author which holds the book models. Untested proposal:

```
var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
   this.author = options.author;
   var authorid = this.author.get("id");
  }
});

var Author = Backbone.Model.extend({
 initialize: function(){
   this.books = new Books( {author:this} );
 }
});
```